# python: understanding multiprocessing for a simple for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multithreading

I have never used multiprocessing module before.

Is there a way a for loop could be made into concurrent subprocesses. like

```
for i in xrange(10): list.append(i)
```

instead of sequential, make it parallel?

I tried using Queue module

```
q = Queue.Queue()

for i in xrange(10):
    q.put(i)


def addto(q):
    new.append(q.get(block=False))


processes = [Process(target=addto, args=(q,))]
for p in processes:
    p.start()
for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

And it gave out a long error, im pasting the last of it:

```
C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.3.3\python-2.7.3.amd64\lib\pickle.pyc in save_global(self, obj, name, pack)
    746             raise PicklingError(
    747                 "Can't pickle %r: it's not found as %s.%s" %
--> 748                 (obj, module, name))
    749         else:
    750             if klass is not obj:

PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'thread.lock'>: it's not found as thread.lock
```

I also see this alot:

```
processes = [Process(target=func, args=(q,x)) for i in some iterable]
```

So okay there is a func(q,x) alright, and i have a map() or for loop/while going inside my function func() so why iteration in processes, again? 
I wouldn't want to loop the whole function using process but just make those particular loops into parallel processes. Why iterate over the target function with args? I mean when i have already q.put it?

What if I do

```
processes = Process(target=addto, args=(q,)).start()
```

Comment: "I mean when i have already q.put it?" Exactly!  Your example is too trivial.  Even without the `q.put()` loop, it's not enough work to justify dividing it among processes.

Comment: @BrianCain I know.its silly right.but i could have used thread instead to understand how they work.i wanted to know how processes work. and specifically the issue for me is making loops parallel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Queue.Queue` is for threadsafe queues, and thread primitives cannot be transferred to other processes. You want [`multiprocessing.Queue`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) instead; simply replace

```
import Queue
q = Queue.Queue()
```

with

```
import multiprocessing
q = multiprocessing.Queue()
```

Additionally, `new` must be of type [`multiprocessing.managers.list`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.list).

However, note that you're just replicating a [`multiprocessing.Pool`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool); you can just write

```
import multiprocessing

new = multiprocessing.Manager().list()
def addto(val):
    new.append(val)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
for i in xrange(10):
    pool.apply_async(addto, (i,))
pool.close()
pool.join()
print(new)
```

Comment: Great insight.I did import Queue from multiprocessing.Okay, ill update what happens with that

Comment: new is still empty new = []

Comment: @user2290820 Updated with a complete example, which works fine for me (by default, it uses a process per virtual CPU, so with a multi-processor machine, you'll even see different results depending on scheduling). Does that example work for you? If not, what error message and output do you get?

Comment: Thanks. I will head back to the multiprocessing docs. this multiprocessing doc is not that simple to understand since it starts off with a bigger example.